# Using Camanjs to alter image and then changing leafletjs image

Tags: javascript, leaflet, data-visualization, camanjs

I am new to data visualization and web development and I am trying to alter this image using camanjs. After I alter this image, I wish to set it up as the background for a map which is using leafletjs. I am not exactly sure how to approach this and would like some help.

Is there some way to get the image url from an image object or saving the image to file, and then using the url of saved image as background for the leaflet object? These are the only solutions I can think of but there might be a better way

Here is how I alter the image

```
Caman('#canvas', function () {
   this.colorize(25, 180, 200, 20);
   this.render();
});
```

And this is how I set up the map

```
// initialize the map
var map = L.map('map', {
   crs: L.CRS.Simple
});

var bounds = [
        [0, 0],
        [300, 300]
    ];

var image = L.imageOverlay(*ALTERED IMAGE URL HER*, bounds, {
   opacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

I do not actually know what to do next and how to get the altered image to be the leaflet map background

Comment: You can use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob and create with the help of `createObjectURL` an URL.

Comment: @Phil so I am trying to create a blob using `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');` and `canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {})` but this keeps returning an undefined object and thus I cant generate a URL, any suggestions?

Comment: I've created a small demo: https://jsbin.com/wijigem/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Phil So I tried using the url but am still running into some error. Leaflet is unable to read the URL and display the image

Comment: I've updated my demo, maybe you can use a base64 string instead.

Comment: @Phil Awesome, this works Thanks!